# Morse Code meta-command sequences?

Tags: morse-code

When using Morse Code as an accessibility/disability communication or input method, are there any non-alphanumeric dot-dash sequences that are more common or more suitable for meta-commands, such as “speak the last string”, “send command string to wheelchair”, or just to enter carriage-returns or capitalize the next letter.

There does already seem to be a common control or meta-command for backspace (6 or 8 dots?)

Comment: Google seems to have recently demo’d an enhancement to Android GBoard to allow predictive speech synthesis via head Switch input for use by some severely handicapped people using some form of Morse code.

Comment: Are you thinking of creating a device that would use such control characters?

Comment: @hotpaw2 Good question.  A quick search didn't turn up any standard other than this that someone started:   https://github.com/agwells/dotdash-keyboard-android/wiki/Wells-extended-Morse-code

Comment: Yes, there is a Morse Code option built into Google's own "GBoard" keyboard since Android 5.0: https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9011881?hl=en Somewhat disappointingly imo, it only has separate buttons for dot and dash entry — no way to use it as a "straight key" that I could find.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try local resources and active websites.  Sometimes a large, vibrant community is better than mediocre standards.

## Morse Codes for Computer Access

https://www.makoa.org/jlubin/morsecode.htm

> ...
>
> I have codes defined in two "groups" and use a code to switch between them. This enables me to reuse the same codes for different functions in different groups. A third code group contains codes that are always active, such as commands to switch between the other code groups.
>
> Modifier keys (Shift, Control & Alt) release after the next code for a non-modifier key is sent. If a modifier key is needed to remain active for multiple keys then the hold/release code can be used to keep it active until the hold/release code is sent again.
>
> To move the mouse pointer, send the code once for the direction (up/down/right/left) then the repeat code (a single sip). The mouse continues to move in that direction until either a single sip or puff will stop it. The standard mouse move is set to move 4 mickeys. When I need to be more precise I send the "mouse zoom" code which changes the mouse moves to 1 mickey.
>
> A " **·** " is a sip and a " **-** " is a puff.
>
> ## Alpha-Numeric Code Group
>
> [image: Alphabet, numbers, and control keys assigned dots and dashes]
>
> ## Mouse/Windows Code Group
>
> [image: Keyboard combinations, cursor movement keys, and mouse movements assigned dots and dashes]
>
> ...

The above website had links to other resources as well.  The above seems to be an article ["Morse Codes for Computer Access" in *Assistive Technology and Electronic Aids for Daily Living*](https://at-eadl.blogspot.com/2018/04/morse-codes-for-computer-access.html).

Answer (score 0):

The "GBoard" software keyboard built into Android since 5.0 offers a [Morse code mode](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9011881), but I have not found thorough documentation. Their [training webapp](http://morse.withgoogle.com/learn) only includes [letters A–Z](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/morse-learn/blob/master/scripts/morse-dictionary.js#L15).

A few command sequences are, however, readily apparent via the UI:

[image: Google's marketing image for Morse keyboard]

Specifically:

- `..--` — space
- `----` — backspace
- `.-.-` — return
- `....-.` — shift [uppercase]
- `.-----` etc. (like numbers with an extra dah) — pick autocomplete suggestion

The author of [this page](http://www.tandemmaster.org/morse_code.html) seems to have been involved with the development of the GBoard interface, but not very many of her punctuation sequences worked for me when I tried it today.

**UPDATE**: I may or may not have disassembled a GBoard APK and tracked down its character mapping: https://gist.github.com/natevw/0fce6b56c606632f8ee780b5d493f94e

Main observations:

- the control characters already visible in the UI (and listed above) appear to be the only ones supported internally.
- there are a few special "extended" characters, such as `.--.--` for `}` and `......` for `^`.